# Where can I get historical intraday pre/post market data for indices?

Tags: market-data, historical-data

I've done a lot of research and can't find any place that allows me to export this data. I know ProRealTime has it, but can't export the data.

I've read some threads about people web scraping the data, but doesn't seem to be a place where I can web scrape any historical intraday pre/post market data.

Many thanks

Comment: The most popular post on this SE lists a whole set of data sources, you can try there.